# window:willPositionSheet:usingRect doesn't get called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, modal-dialog

I've a Cocoa window controller defined that's overriding the method for window:willPositionSheet, but when the dialog opens it doesn't get called.

```
- (NSRect)window:(NSWindow *)window willPositionSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet usingRect:(NSRect)rect
{
return rect;
}
```

An important fact, the dialog is a sheet and the parent is a Carbon window passed as a Cocoa reference when the sheet dialog is created.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

That is an `NSWindow` delegate method, so you'll need to set your window controller as the delegate of your window, either by connecting the window's delegate outlet to File's Owner in Interface Builder or by calling the window's `‑setDelegate:` method.

Comment: Thanks Rob!
Well, I'm think is what I'm doing in: 
[theApp beginSheet:[dialog window] 
 modalForWindow:window 
 modalDelegate:dialog 
didEndSelector:@selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) 
 contextInfo:nil];

dialog extends from NSWindowController.

I've also tried setting the delegate after the creation, but the method still doesn't get called.

Comment: No, you need to set an object as the delegate of your `window` object. This is completely different to the modal delegate you assign in the `beginSheet:…` method. That is a temporary delegate that receives messages from the modal dialog. You need a delegate for your main window, the one that the sheet attaches to, and in that delegate you must implement the `window:willPositionSheet:usingRect:` method.

Comment: Rob, I'm afraid to tell you I've tried creating a new class extending NSObject<NsWindowDelegate> and implemented the method window:willPositionSheet:usingRect, and after the beginSheet is called  I create the delegate object and set to the main window by setDelegate: but window:willPositionSheet:usingRect still doesn't get called.

Comment: The method gets called fine if you do what @RobKeniger says re: setting a window delegate. But it only works for non-full screen windows. When the window is full screen, this method is no longer getting called. And that's still the case as of OS X 10.10 (haven't checked 10.11 yet). Perhaps a bug report is in order?